# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I got this error message below:

```
Ld /Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iFly.app/iFly normal i386
    cd /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Intermediates/iFly.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iFly.build/Objects-normal/i386/iFly.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lxml2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -lxml2 -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics /Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RestKit/RestKit /Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a -o /Users/kIT98K/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iFly-cijrdcwdnrwowmgcazhvczqzkctd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iFly.app/iFly

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I try to use xcodebuild -target to build for more info,

```
Ld build/Release-iphoneos/iFly.app/iFly normal armv7
    cd /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/build/iFly.build/Release-iphoneos/iFly.build/Objects-normal/armv7/iFly.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lxml2 -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -lxml2 -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/RestKit/build/Release/RestKit.framework/RestKit /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/RestKit/build/Release-iphoneos/libRestKit.a -o /Users/kIT98K/proooo2/VPN38/iFly/build/Release-iphoneos/iFly.app/iFly
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Release-iphoneos/iFly.app/iFly normal armv7
(1 failure)
```

Please help, been on this for a week searching everywhere before this message. 
thanks.

Comment: full build log would help a lot

Comment: @hoha: I think he claims that is the full build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem through the site https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installation-Troubleshooting .

Answer (score 2):

Choose your build target and in "Build Phases" -> "Target Dependencies", add the project you used (which I guess is RestKit) to the list.

Comment: Yes,I did it.The problem is I include a wrong "Target Dependencies"